# How to write the below snippet in python?

Tags: python

```
if(stuckSomewhere()||lost() == true)
{
   stuckSomewhere().stop();
   lost().stop();
   debugAvailableOptions();
}
```

I'm pretty much newbie for python. I was exploring python but I'm unable to come to a solution for this snippet.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.
especially provide input, desired output and your attempt at coding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the syntax to be python:

```
if (stuckSomewhere() or lost()) == True:
   stuckSomewhere().stop()
   lost().stop()
   debugAvailableOptions()
```

But otherwise, I have no idea what is code is supposed to do.